# Comparar elementos de vetores no R, de tamanho diferentes

Tags: r, array

Minha intenção aqui é encontrar os elementos em comum entre a e b.

```
a <- seq(from=1, to=5, by=1)
b <- seq(from=5, to=13, by=1)
x <- which(a==b)

Warning message:
In a == b : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: A pergunta está muito confusa. O que tu deseja é encontrar os elementos em comum entre `a` e `b`? Por exemplo, a resposta do teu código acima deveria ser `5`?

Comment: exato. obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Use o comando `intersect`:

```
a <- seq(from=1, to=5, by=1)
b <- seq(from=5, to=13, by=1)
intersect(a, b)
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma é usar o operador `%in%`:

```
> a %in% b
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

O operador `%in%` retorna um vetor de TRUE ou FALSE do mesmo tamanho do vetor da esquerda. TRUE indica que o elemento está presente no vetor da direita e FALSE indica que não está.

Fazendo o subsetting usando o resultado de `%in%`, você encontra os elementos que estão na intersecção.

```
> a[a %in% b]
[1] 5
```